# random иногда только берет 1(Storages), а иногда только 2(Orders) как можно чтобы выходило "1 1 2 1 1 2 2 1" таким образом

Tags: c#

```
public class DrugStoresTypes : DrugStores
{
    public string OrderAndStorage { get; set; }

    readonly Random _random = new Random();
    public const string Storages = "Storages";
    public const string Orders = "Orders";

    public DrugStoresTypes()
    {
        OrderAndStorage = _random.Next(1, 3) == 1 ? Storages : Orders;
    }

}
```

---

**UPD:**
вот я обращаюсь к Orders и Storage.

```
private void CheckFiltrOnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    var filtr = string.Format("OrderAndStorage = '{0}'","empty");

    if (checkStorage.Checked)
        filtr = string.Format("OrderAndStorage = '{0}'", DrugStoresTypes.Storages);

    if (checkOrders.Checked)
        filtr = string.Format("OrderAndStorage = '{0}'", DrugStoresTypes.Orders);


    if (checkStorage.Checked && checkOrders.Checked)
        filtr = string.Format("OrderAndStorage = '{0}' or OrderAndStorage = '{1}'", DrugStoresTypes.Storages, DrugStoresTypes.Orders);

    gridSource.Filter = filtr;
}
```

Comment: но ведь это не случайная последовательность?

Comment: Всегда, это когда вы обращаетесь к полю OrderAndStorage, которое вы инициализировали в конструкторе?

Comment: 1.Я бы хотель сделать случайную последовательност.
2.Да всегда

Answer (score 4):

В вашем случае вы инициализируете свойство OrderAndStorage случайным значением в конструкторе, т.е. единожды, и в дальнейшем обращаясь к свойству получаете всегда одно и тоже значение. Для того, что бы каждый раз получать случайное значение, надо при каждом обращении к свойству OrderAndStorage генерировать новое значение, наприме так:

```
public class DrugStoresTypes : DrugStores
{
    readonly Random _random = new Random();
    public const string Storages = "Storages";
    public const string Orders = "Orders";

    public string OrderAndStorage => _random.Next(1, 3) == 1 ? Storages : Orders;
}
```

что эквивалентно

```
public string OrderAndStorage 
{
   get { return _random.Next(1, 3) == 1 ? Storages : Orders; }
}
```

Comment: добавь пояснение в ответ, почему это сработает и чем отличается от кода в вопросе